# Unable to surpass "is not clickable at point (864,632) because another element <p> obscures it" after many tries

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a list of elements from a drop down menu

```
    <header class="module module__hd">
        <select id="historical-data-select" class="historical-data-select" onchange="getProductData(this.value)" style="">
            
            <option class="menuitem" value="X1">Description1</option>
            
            <option class="menuitem" value="X2">Description2</option>
            ...
            ...
        </select>
    </header>
```

I am using the following code to click each element `X1` and `X2`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
# navigate to the page
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('historical-data-select'))
print(select.options)
menu_items=[elem.text for elem in select.options]
select.select_by_visible_text(menu_items[-1])
```

I am having the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <select id="historical-data-select" class="historical-data-select"> is not clickable at point (864,632) because another element <p> obscures it
```

I tried to use another method to select `X1`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", select.options[0])
```

It returns no error, but when examining `driver.page_source`, the page is not rendered as I wish.

How can I overcome this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: Figure out which P is blocking access. Look at the page and find the SELECT you are trying to access. Which P is blocking/covering it? I don't suppose you can share the URL?

Comment: You need to wait for some time while selecting item from drop down and page get refreshed and then grab driver.page_source.

Comment: @jeffC , no problem, the URL is 'https://markets.cboe.com/us/futures/market_statistics/historical_data/'

Comment: @Kunduk , I am waiting enough time in python console such as 20, 30 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting problem because of the security button where you need to select I agree. Use WebDriverWait()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://markets.cboe.com/us/futures/market_statistics/historical_data/")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='I agree']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"historical-data-select")))

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('historical-data-select'))
print(len(select.options))
menu_items=[elem.text for elem in select.options]
print(menu_items)
select.select_by_visible_text(menu_items[-1])
time.sleep(3)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: If you are going to use more than one `WebDriverWait(driver,10)`, you should just declare a variable so that it's easier to reuse. Also, you should replace the `time.sleep(3)` with another wait as a better practice.